# Como Instalar Appium

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou tentando instar o Appium no Android Studio, mas não estou sabendo como fazer. Como posso instalar o **Appium** no **Android Studio** ?

Comment: Mas está dando algum erro? Qual é o problema?

Comment: Não estou sabendo como instalar, porque pelo que entendi são arquivos .js e não sei como utiliza-los ou instala-los ,etc....

Comment: Mas você quer implementar o serviço na sua aplicação ou está falando de algum tipo de plugin?

Comment: Quero implementar o serviço na minha aplicação

Comment: então não tem que ser um arquivo .js e sim .jar, que é o que o java entende.

Comment: Tem algum link aonde eu possa pegar esse .jar porque estou me matando de procurar mas até um pouco difícil..rs

Comment: Já tentou no proprio site do Appium ?

Comment: https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3Aio.appium%20a%3Ajava-client

Comment: Consegui, obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar o **Appium** em sua aplicação, deve baixar primeiro a [**biblioteca Appium**](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3Aio.appium%20a%3Ajava-client), cuja extensão é `.jar`. Depois basta seguir o [tutorial inicial](https://appium.io/slate/en/tutorial/android.html?ruby#install-android) que se identifica no próprio site do Appium.